# Python: extract questions from a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a quite simple problem but I don't find a smart way to do it.

I have a string like this:

```
"""Q 1
wording of question 1
eventually on many lines
Q 2
wording of question 2
Q 3
wording of question 3
Q 4
wording of question 4
"""
```

I just want to extract each question and their wording in a list like this:

```
['Q 1\nwording of question 1\neventually on many lines','Q 2\nwording of question 2','Q 3\nwording of question 3','Q 4\nwording of question 4']
```

I tried with a pattern like this:

```
(Q \d.+?)Q \d
```

But since, for example, `Q 2` is in the pattern for `Q 1` I can't get `Q 2` with findall because the two patterns overlap.

I thought of a solution using the end of the string but I would need to search from the end of the string and it doesn't seem to be feasible in Python.

Does anybody has a solution to this ?

Comment: `re.split(r'\s+^(?=Q +\d)', s, re.M)`, [demo](https://ideone.com/lVMyXw). `re.findall(r'^Q +\d.*(?:\n(?!Q \d).*)*', s, re.M)` - [demo](https://ideone.com/bbf3CZ)

Comment: It's working! could you please explain at least the one with findall?

Comment: It's ok, I get it reading the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: You know, this type of questions is regular on SO. I have answered dozens of similar questions. I need to find a good thread on this topic and close the question as a duplicate but not sure which one to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting [Wiktor Stribiżew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) solution as an answer since this worked for my purposes.

```
text = """Q 1
wording of question 1
eventually on many lines
Q 2
wording of question 2
Q 3
wording of question 3
Q 4
wording of question 4
"""

import re

def extract_questions(text):

    q_list = re.findall(r'^Q +\d.*(?:\n(?!Q \d).*)*', text, re.M)
    
    return q_list


extract_questions(text)
```

Returns:

```
['Q 1\nwording of question 1\neventually on many lines',
 'Q 2\nwording of question 2',
 'Q 3\nwording of question 3',
 'Q 4\nwording of question 4\n']
```